# What namespace to use to get the View class?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, view

I started of as a strict API in my project but now I want to render a view, so I added an action as follows.

```
[HttpGet("login")]
public IActionResult LogIn([FromQuery] string returnUrl)
{
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  ...
  return View("Login");
}
```

I also added a file called *Login.cshtml* in the directory *Views/Account* (while the controller above is located in directory *Controllers*.

The problem is that the symbol can't be resolved, says the computer. I know that the syntax is correct (as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2#specifying-a-view-name)) so I'm assuming that it's a *using Xxx* that is to be added. Funny enough, I haven't found docs for it and I simply don't know how to make it available to my my project.

How can I resolve *View* not being recognized?

I noticed that changing the inheritance from [*ControllerBase*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-2.1) (where it's said *without view support* to *Controller* removes the error but it seems like going back to pre-Core time and doing it as we did in the old MVC. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but it seems like going back to pre-Core time and doing it as we did in the old MVC

I don’t understand what you want to say with this. ASP.NET Core is designed to closely match classic ASP.NET MVC in its usage, so that you don’t need to change *everything* when migrating. And also because the previous usage wasn’t *bad*. So just because you do something that you already did back then does not mean that this is something bad. You are still running a completely different framework.

That being said, if you want to use MVC views, your controller should inherit from [`Controller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller) instead of [`ControllerBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase). You could also directly return a [`ViewResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewresult) instead but just inheriting from `Controller` is usually simpler to use. Note that you generally don’t have a disadvantage from doing so.

And if you worry about adding MVC view functionality to your API controllers, you can just use separate controllers for that purpose then.